# How to change port form 8080 to 80 with Apache Tomcat/8.0.29 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu

The answers given in 
[How to change the port of Tomcat from 8080 to 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80) and 
[Tomcat7 bind to port 80 fails in Ubuntu 14.04LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272666/tomcat7-bind-to-port-80-fails-in-ubuntu-14-04lts)
works good for tomcat7, but as I couldn't do a 'apt-get' to install tomcat8, the files created by default during the installation of tomcat7 at /etc/default/ couldn't be found while installing tomcat8 manually.

Is there any other way to change port form 8080 to 80 after manually installing tomcat8 on Ubuntu 14.04 EC2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already changed the Connector port="8080" to "80".

Answer (score 2):

If you install tomcat8 with apt-get , take a look at
/etc/default/tomcat8

Theres a directive at the end of the file :
AUTHBIND=yes

Set it to yes

Answer (score 0):

What I did is very simple and it worked. I copied and pasted my tomcat folder to /etc and of course changed the Connector port from 8080 to 80 in tomcat/conf/server.xml.

I got few tips from https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=99847 where he suggested :-
***Moving /etc/default/tomcat to /etc and use the defaults in
/etc/init.d/tomcat instead.***

Comment: Hello.. doing it didn't work for me. Just copying moving tomcat's folder to /etc/ didn't resolve at all.
The /etc/default/tomcat8 file should exist? Could you please share more informations? I appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: The /etc/default/tomcat8 will be created if you would installed tomcat through apt-get